# Как убрать область виджета WordPress?

Tags: веб-программирование, wordpress

Всем Hi! Есть сайт на WordPress 3.9.1 
На страницах мне не нужны виждены, ни один! Я убрал их с правой панели (области) Все гуд, но сама область осталось, а визуально это некрасиво - страница как бы смещена влево вместо центра. Как полностью убрать область виджета?

Answer (score 1):

укажи display:none для дива в котором находиться виджет

Comment: в каком файле?

Answer (score 1):

Тут многое зависит от темы, которую вы используете.
Зачастую помогает зайти в папку с вашей темой и очистить всё содержимое файлы sidebar.php
Если вы напишете какая у вас тема, то сможем точно написать что убрать

Answer (score 1):

Закомментируй саму область:

```
     $args_rigth_text = array(
    'name'          => __( 'Топ Евы', 'wob_theme' ),
        'id'            => 'wob_theme_rigth',
    'description'   => 'Колонка с произвольным текстом',
        'class'         => 'sidebox widget',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="%1$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h4>',
    'after_title'   => '</h4>' );
     register_sidebar($args_rigth_text);
```

И в файле sidebar.php или sidebar-sample.php найди нужный тебе кусок кода, заранее получив его в инспекторе браузера.